# How to download tar.gz and uppack it to hdfs without downloading the whole file to local disk?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, command-line-interface, tar

I would like to extract tar.gz files from web directly into hdfs.
Skipping the download-to-local-disk phase as the files can be very big.

This all from simple cmd line script (bash, wget etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like this one liner works:

```
wget -O - http://...tar.gz | tar xfz - --to-stodout | hadoop dfs -put - /somepath
```

Comment: You're sure that doesn't touch on local disk?

Comment: I assume it may touch local disk for some buffering. The point is that it doesn't require the whole file to be on a disk at once.

Comment: @LoïcGuzzetta which part?

Comment: @Piotr all of it. It will only write a file named "-" on hdfs. 
And I'm not even talking about the case if the tar archive is also composed of multiple folders and sub folders and sub files, which this command won't be able to rebuild on hdfs.